Barn door ideas
I want to replace the pillars in this opening and put a barn door there. The opening measures approximately 8 feet wide and 8 feet tall. I've already purchased 9-foot wide barn door hardware with the intention of building two 4.5-foot wide doors. However, I've then noticed that the arch narrows in the middle, posing potential issues with securing the hardware to studs, even with a headboard. I've explored ceiling-mounted barn doors as well, but they would require cutting into the molding and may cause a large gap. What other options do I have? Are there alternative solutions to hang the door or any other solution to separate the room with doors?
https://imgur.com/sdotyFc

Replace the pillars with what? Removing them to "replace" with a barn door (your apparent intent) may lead to structural issues, depending why the pillars are there and what they are supporting. Barn doors don't support much of anything but themselves.

Comments: 1. Removing the columns and installing a barn door will require filling in the arch with framing and drywall, because a barn door will require more head space than is available over the arch. 2. Installing a barn door will cover the outlet to the left whenever the door is open.  3. Do you have enough wall space to the left for the door?

Alternatives: 1. French doors—but gets complicated on the right side of the opening due to sofa and front door. 2. Some kind of accordion door.  3. Some kind of rollup door.  4. Beaded curtain?
